# Extraction of data from Google Maps using MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone tell me how I can extract Data from Google Maps database?
I want to extract information based on the name.
For eg: select name, address, coordinates from maps_table where name like 'regex_expression'

Please help me on how to do this with Google Maps

Comment: Why do you think that is possible?

Comment: I just wanna know how many branches of a bank are present in a specific location. The google maps search does it, but I want to store the locations of those branches automatically all at a time instead of googling and noting down the locations manually for every branch of the bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fetch google maps information in a database or any such entity which stores bulk information .So a discussion on how to retrieve it from a database is hypothetical as Google Maps data is not meant to reside in a DB.

Section 10.1 of Google Maps' Terms of Use [1] says :

(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

(c) No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content. You must not use the Service in a manner that gives you or any other person access to mass downloads or bulk feeds of any Content, including but not limited to numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, visible map data, or places data (including business listings). For example, you are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content contained in the Maps API(s).